# Downsized images look different in canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I am building a site where I show the map of a campus. I show the same map twice: 1) I draw a canvas where I draw the full image (approx. 1500px). 2) a pre built conponent where the image is downsized before it is sent to the client. Because the div where I place these in is limited to 465px I obviously have to downsize. But when I look at the canvas with the default 100% zoom (firefox) on a 1080p screen it looks very bad. I can zoom in to get a higher quality.

My question is: Why does the canvas look so bad in comparison to the img?

Comment: Without seeing what you did, it's hard to see what you did wrong. A blind guess though: Are you setting canvas width and height property before drawing to it? If so, you should be able to call `drawImage(img,0,0)` If you need more params, here lies your problem.

Comment: oh and an other blind guess: if you are setting the canvas width and height properly, are you using the image's width and height, or its naturalWidth and naturalHeight?